# SQL Attach 'User.Identity.Name' along with excel data import into SQL Server database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am using VS2005 C# and SQL Server 2005.

I have an Excel file import which imports the data in a spreadsheet into the database.

However, in order to improve on it, I would like to implement some kind of 'logging' to each import.

For every row of data that the user import, there will be a column which will store the logged-in-user's name, which is `User.Identity.Name`.

Below is a code snippet of my excel import code:

```
// Create Connection to Excel Workbook
string connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + strUploadFileName + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";

using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connStr))
{
   OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("Select [User ID], [Username], [Age], [Address], [Date of Reg], [Membership Type], [Membership Expiry] FROM [sheet1$]", connection);
   //would like to insert 'User.Identity.Name' into column 'userlog'

   connection.Open();
   Console.WriteLine("Connection Opened");

   // Create DbDataReader to Data Worksheet
   using (DbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
   {
      // SQL Server Connection String
      string sqlConnectionString = "Data Source=<DS>";

      // Bulk Copy to SQL Server
      using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString))
      {
         bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "UserData";
         bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr);
      }
   }
}
```

I have no idea how I can do it because the `SELECT` statement takes only variable from the `sheet1$` of the data which I import, so I have no clue how I can include another variable from another source into the sql query. I need suggestions from experienced.

Thank you guys for any help in advance.

EDIT:

I have another import method for `.csv` type. As the `SELECT` statement is not the same as the one i used for `.xls`, how should I change it? Below is a code snippet:

```
string dir = @"C:\...\UploadFiles";
string mycsv = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + strExtension;
// Save the Excel spreadsheet on server. 
UserImport.SaveAs(dir + mycsv);

// Create Connection to Excel Workbook
string connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + dir + 
                 ";Extended Properties=Text;";
using (OleDbConnection ExcelConnection = new OleDbConnection(connStr))
{
     OleDbCommand ExcelCommand = new OleDbCommand(
          "SELECT [User ID], [Username], [Age], [Address], 
           [Date of Reg], [Membership Type], [Membership Expiry] 
           FROM " + mycsv, ExcelConnection);

     OleDbDataAdapter ExcelAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(ExcelCommand);
     ExcelConnection.Open();

     using (DbDataReader dr = ExcelCommand.ExecuteReader())
     {
         // SQL Server Connection String
         string sqlConnectionString = "Data Source=<DS>";

         // Bulk Copy to SQL Server
         using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConnectionString))
         {
             bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "UserData";
             bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dr);
             //Response.Write("<script>alert('User Data imported');</script>");
         }
     }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try extending your select clause.

```
string selectStmt = string.Format("Select [User ID], [Username], [Age], [Address], 
                         [Date of Reg], [Membership Type], [Membership Expiry],  
                         '{0}' as [userlog] FROM [sheet1$]", User.Identity.Name);
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(selectStmt, connection);
```

Updated according to your *edited question*

```
string selectStmt = string.Format("SELECT [User ID], [Username], [Age], [Address], 
       [Date of Reg], [Membership Type], [Membership Expiry],'{0}' as [userlog]  
       FROM {1}", User.Identity.Name, mycsv);
```

Comment: Hi Pilgerstorfer, I'm sorry, I made a mistake in the sql query. I am suppose to make an `INSERT` statement for it. How should I change the query? Thank you

Comment: I have came up with the update query. thanks a lot, your solution is what I am looking for.

Comment: Sorry to trouble you, but I have another SQL query which is sort of different from the one before that. Mind taking a look at it? Thanks a lot

Comment: If you want to Add user.Identity.Name too - have a look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) which will contain both your Excel data and your identity name, then bulk copy this DataTable to your SQL Server.

See this [link](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=323) for more information  on Bulk insert DataTable.